# Creating a encrypted virtual hard disk that is dynamic sizing

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, truecrypt, veracrypt

I have a network drive that is huge in capacity and shared amongst several people. I want to use it to store some archived contents but I do not want others to be able to read it.

I am thinking of creating a virtual encrypted disk on top of a physical file on that network drive. After some researching, I know `veracrypt` or `truecrypt` can create a file and mount the fs automatically, but I need to allocate and reserve the space beforehand. I wish it could be like virtualbox and its `vdi` file format, which is small at first and extensible overtime. Also, the mounting takes very long, which is probably due to its large size.

For your info, the network drive has 20TB free space, I need to use around 500GB-1TB. Writing speed on network cable is around 95MB/s.

Is there any better alternatives to VeraCrypt? Other suggested approaches are also appreciated. Bonus point if it can work on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different encryption type, that encrypts files & folders. Like [eCryptfs](http://ecryptfs.org/) or [EncFS](http://www.arg0.net/encfs).

They mount to a folder and only encrypt files as needed, so almost no extra disk space is needed aside from a few config files.

I'm pretty sure windows has it's own similar directory-only encryption too, or I think there are windows ports of the above.

Also see arch linux's [Disk Encryption](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_encryption) wiki, especially the section on [Available methods](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_encryption#Available_methods) - stacked files vs block device.

---

You could also look into just not allowing those users to read those folders, if the network drive supports users & permissions. No special filesystem or encryption required.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need Gbit speeds, you might be able to use a QEMU disk image (qcow2), that can be sparse, compressed and encrypted all at once. Accessing it with `qemu-nbd` will make it mountable for local use.

This also puts you in a situation, where virtualizing the whole thing in the future is a breeze.

Comment: Is qemu-nbd for linux only, or win & mac too? And it doesn't have to run a whole virtual machine, just creates/reads/writes the disk format? Sounds interesting, could you show the commands to quickly create a 
"disk" (and format/mount if it's different from a regular disk)?